# Consume Dropbox httpwebrequest to upload file to dropbox with asp.net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an 'ASP.NET core 3.1'  web   application and I use Dropbox API to upload a file to  root folder of dropbox ,i just have the AppKey and AppSecret
then how i will consume httpwebrequest and provide to my users to upload file to own dropbox account???
plz anyone help me